# How to put two select attributes (which are in different forms) side by side using html & css

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, jsp

I need to put two select types side by side which re in different forms

Float and span are not working, I have also tried position-property but of no use.

Below is the HTML code,

```css
form.aui .field-group {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 145px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 1px 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz-page-panel">
  <div class="xyz-page-panel-inner">
    <section class="xyz-page-panel-content">
      <div id="searchType">
        <form class="xyz">
          <div class="field-group">
            <label for="one-two-id">Search Type  </label>
            <select name="searchType" class="select long-field" id="one-two-id">
              <option value="one">one</option>
              <option value="two">two</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form class="xyz">
          <div class="field-group">
            <label for="search-options-id">Search field </label>
            <select class="select long-field" id="productName">
              <option value="one">one</option>
              <option value="two">two</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `form` elements themselves are `block` by default, and the parent `div` presumably as well. You need to float the form or the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
.xyz-page-panel-content {
  display: flex;
}
```

It's important that you recognize the elements in your structure that are siblings. In your case it's

```
<div class="xyz-page-panel">
  <div class="xyz-page-panel-inner">
    <section class="xyz-page-panel-content">
      <!-- sibling 1 -->
      <div id="searchType">
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
      <!-- sibling 2 -->
      <div>
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

For `display: flex` to work, you must assign this rule to the parent element of those who are meant to be next to each other. If those are not siblings, you have to use some other strategy or change the HTML structure.

You could use float instead by floating the siblings. I don't like using float for layout purposes like these, so I don't show it in action.

```
.xyz-page-panel-content > * {
  float: left ;
}
```

```css
form.aui .field-group {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 145px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 1px 0;
  width: 100%
}

.xyz-page-panel-content {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz-page-panel">
  <div class="xyz-page-panel-inner">
    <section class="xyz-page-panel-content">
      <div id="searchType">
        <form class="xyz">
          <div class="field-group">
            <label for="one-two-id">Search Type  </label>
            <select name="searchType" class="select long-field" id="one-two-id">
              <option value="one">one</option>
              <option value="two">two</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form class="xyz">
          <div class="field-group">
            <label for="search-options-id">Search field </label>
            <select class="select long-field" id="productName">
              <option value="one">one</option>
              <option value="two">two</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to float the divs outside the form tags. This should work.

```
#searchType {
  float:left;
}
```

[Like this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqzmyW)